# Android Fragment transaction from list's element

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an ArrayAdapter `MealAdapter` and list's element `meal_item`, there are a few textviews and FrameLayout. I want to put fragment `MealDetails` in this FrameLayout by click on imageview. `MealAdapter` isn't used in Activity but in another fragment.

My item is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!--icon-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/meal_number_icon"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--name-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/protein_source_name"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/fat_source_name"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/carb_source_name"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/vegetable_source_name"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/protein_source_weight"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/fat_source_weight"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/carb_source_weight"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/vegetable_source_weight"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        <!-- refreshMeal -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/meal_accept_icon"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--info-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/info_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/meal_details_icon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:tint="#8a000000"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/meal_frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and adapter:

```
public class MealAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();
    private Context context;

    public MealAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class DataHandler{
        ImageView numberIcon;
        ImageView detailsIcon;
        ImageView acceptIcon;

        TextView proteinSourceName;
        TextView fatSourceName;
        TextView carbSourceName;
        TextView vegetableSourceName;

        TextView proteinSourceWeight;
        TextView fatSourceWeight;
        TextView carbSourceWeight;
        TextView vegetableSourceWeight;

        FrameLayout detailsLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final DataHandler dataHandler;

        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_item,parent,false);
            dataHandler = new DataHandler();

            dataHandler.numberIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.meal_number_icon);
            dataHandler.detailsIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.meal_details_icon);
            dataHandler.acceptIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.meal_accept_icon);

            dataHandler.proteinSourceName =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.protein_source_name);
            dataHandler.fatSourceName =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fat_source_name);
            dataHandler.carbSourceName =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carb_source_name);
            dataHandler.vegetableSourceName =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vegetable_source_name);

            dataHandler.proteinSourceWeight =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.protein_source_weight);
            dataHandler.fatSourceWeight =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fat_source_weight);
            dataHandler.carbSourceWeight =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carb_source_weight);
            dataHandler.vegetableSourceWeight =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vegetable_source_weight);

            dataHandler.detailsLayout=(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.meal_frameLayout);
            view.setTag(dataHandler);

        }
        else{
            dataHandler=(DataHandler) view.getTag();
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final MealDataProvider mealDataProvider;
        mealDataProvider = (MealDataProvider) this.getItem(position);

        dataHandler.numberIcon.setImageResource(mealDataProvider.getNumberIcon());
        dataHandler.detailsIcon.setImageResource(mealDataProvider.getShowIcon());
        dataHandler.acceptIcon.setImageResource(mealDataProvider.getAcceptIcon());

        dataHandler.proteinSourceName.setText(mealDataProvider.getProteinSourceName());
        dataHandler.fatSourceName.setText(mealDataProvider.getFatSourceName());
        dataHandler.carbSourceName.setText(mealDataProvider.getCarbSourceName());
        dataHandler.vegetableSourceName.setText(mealDataProvider.getVegetableSourceName());

        dataHandler.proteinSourceWeight.setText(mealDataProvider.getProteinSourceWeight());
        dataHandler.fatSourceWeight.setText(mealDataProvider.getFatSourceWeight());
        dataHandler.carbSourceWeight.setText(mealDataProvider.getCarbSourceWeight());
        dataHandler.vegetableSourceWeight.setText(mealDataProvider.getVegetableSourceWeight());


        dataHandler.detailsIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MealDetails mealDetails = new MealDetails();
                FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(dataHandler.detailsLayout.getId(),mealDetails);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

`onClick` method works (there is "click" toast) but nothing else happens, the is nothing in AndroidMonitor if I `click dataHandler.detailsIcon`.

How is it possible to put fragment in `framelayout` in list's element?

**Edit**
I forgot about `commit()`, so now it works but only for `FrameLayout` from first list's element. It doesn't matter which list's element I click, fragment `MealDetails` is always place in the same FrameLayout.
Probably because every FrameLayout have the same id(?) is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to `commit()` your FragmentTransaction.

If you don't commit it, nothing will happen. Android Studio should be warning about this as well.

Comment: Thanks man! It works but there is another problem (I edited my post)

Comment: I got it by changing `dataHandler.detailsLayout` id to element's number from DataProvider, so every list's element has FrameLayout with unique id